# Pass random state to setRandom with RcppEigen

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp

Is there a way to pass the random state to Eigen's `setRandom` with RcppEigen or do I need to use `runif`?

Here is an example:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppEigen.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using  Eigen::MatrixXd;
using  Eigen::VectorXd;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector fx() {
  RNGScope   scope;
  MatrixXd   x(3,2);
  x=x.setRandom();
  x.col(1)=as<VectorXd>(runif(3,0,1));

return wrap(x);
}
```

Testing it:

```
set.seed(42); fx()
#           [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] -0.8105760 0.9148060
#[2,]  0.6498853 0.9370754
#[3,]  0.6221027 0.2861395

set.seed(42); fx()
#           [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] -0.9449154 0.9148060
#[2,]  0.8063267 0.9370754
#[3,] -0.0673205 0.2861395
```

Note how column 2 (i.e., `runif`) is reproducible, but column 1 (i.e., `setRandom`) is not.

Answer (score 3):

The RNG in Eigen is orthogonal to R's RNGs.  We have `RNGScope` to deal with R and allow you to `set.seed()` as you know; what you do with Eigen's RNG is separate.

In particular, you would have to add the glue to register Eigen's RNG as a user-provided RNG for R.  By default, R is unaware of Eigen,  which makes sense as R users expect R's RNGs.

Your issue here seems to be a vanilla 'programming with Eigen' issue where you fail to initialize the Eigen RNG.  It has nothing to do with Rcpp.

*Edit:* Here is your example, corrected. Turns out Eigen uses the system RNG, so you need `srand()` to seed it.

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/roland.cpp")
R> set.seed(42); fx(42)
          [,1]     [,2]
[1,] -0.933060 0.914806
[2,] -0.340072 0.937075
[3,]  0.381271 0.286140
R> set.seed(42); fx(42)
          [,1]     [,2]
[1,] -0.933060 0.914806
[2,] -0.340072 0.937075
[3,]  0.381271 0.286140
R>
```

It uses this modified version of your code:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppEigen.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using  Eigen::MatrixXd;
using  Eigen::VectorXd;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

  RNGScope   scope;
  MatrixXd   x(3,2);
  srand(seed);
  x=x.setRandom();
  x.col(1)=as<VectorXd>(runif(3,0,1));

  return wrap(x);
}
```

*Edit 2 in response to OP's comments:*

I would not expect much of a speed difference between `Rcpp::runif()` and the `srand()` calls made by Eigen, so you are still stuck with the fact that `srand()` has been having issues, and is possibly behaving differently between systems.

Quick demo script:

```
#include <RcppEigen.h> 

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector v1(int n) {
  return Rcpp::runif(n);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector v2(int n) {
  Eigen::VectorXd   x(n);
  x = x.setRandom();
  return Rcpp::wrap(x);
}

/*** R
library(rbenchmark)
N <- 1e7
benchmark(v1(N), v2(N))
*/
```

which produces

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/roland.cpp")

R> library(rbenchmark)

R> N <- 1e7

R> benchmark(v1(N), v2(N))
   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 v1(N)          100  12.633    1.000    11.356    1.261          0         0
2 v2(N)          100  17.222    1.363    13.981    3.198          0         0
R>
```

and note that RcppEigen is *slower* here even in a *simpler* setup of just creating vectors.  But we are talking microseconds here and that is probably not something I'd worry about either way in a *real* application which will most likely have other bottlenecks.

Comment: Yes, I also found I can use `srand`, but that means I have to use a parameter for the seed. I can certainly do that, but then I have to handle interfacing with `set.seed` at the R level, which seems less than optimal.

Comment: Did you see what I said about *being orthogonal* ? These are **two different RNGs** and one of them is actually not that good. But in short, when you insist on using two different RNGs you also need to seed two different RNGs. No Free Lunch, and all that.

Comment: I understand that. I'll also benchmark how fast the `as<VectorXd>(runif(3,0,1));` alternative is. If it is too slow, I can use `sample.int(2^31-1, 1)` to get an integer that I pass to `srand`.

Comment: You still have not explained why you insist on `srand()`. It is system-dependent, and (at least on some system) not very good.  Use R's RNGs until you have a good reason not to. You have not provided such a reason.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. `setRandom` is much faster than `as<VectorXd>(runif())` (for creating a vector of the same length). I now use `runif`, but since it is used in a loop, I create n times the number of random numbers I need for one iteration and update this if the `while` loop exhausts the pre-calculated randoms. The problem is that n is hard to optimize. Too small means too many calls to `runif`, too large means too much memory demand and also gets slow. The optimum depends on user input, so I set a sensible default and give the user the option of adjusting it ...

Comment: @Roland I have my doubts. Drawing uniforms from an RNG is cheap; you may be measuring something else. See my edit above.

Comment: I need the randoms in an Eigen vector. So, we need to include `Rcpp::as<Eigen::VectorXd>` in the benchmarks and type conversion is slow. I've tried to avoid that using `Eigen::Map`, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Why do you insists on converting an Eigen matrix to an Eigen vector?  I updated your code to directly create a vector making it more efficient.  Anyway, you seem to have some religious belief system here which I can't touch so I stop now.

Comment: I don't convert an Eigen matrix to an Eigen vector. I convert an Rcpp::NumericVector (the result of `runif`) to an Eigen vector. And I do that to use some of Eigen's matrix algebra functions. Nothing religious about that. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: When I change the one line to `Eigen::VectorXd x = Rcpp::as<Eigen::VectorXd>(Rcpp::runif(n));` then the resulting timings are *still near-identical* disproving your claim the (likely inferior) `srand` is faster. RNG calls are not the cost you need to care about as I have been telling you from the start.